# Creating patch of a git revision with Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, patch

Is it possible at all?

It works with SourceTree by selecting a particular version in the history of the project, right clicking it and selecting `create patch`.
But the same option is disabled in Intellij for this setup.

Comment: Read about the `git format-patch` https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch

Comment: I ment getting that on Intellij GUI for a one single version. I know that everything works on git console :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be there in the Version Control tab. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-patches.html

> Creating Patches
>
> IntelliJ IDEA suggests two ways of creating patches:
>
> 1. On the base of revisions, either local or committed to the repository
> 2. On the base of revisions stored in the local history.
>
> To create a patch file
>
> 1. In the Local Changes tab or the Repository tab of the Version Control
>      tool window, select a change or changelist you want to create a patch
>      for.
> 2. On the main Version Control menu or on the context menu of the
>      selection, choose Create patch. 
>      [image]
> 3. In the Create Patch dialog box that opens, review the list
>      of changed files, and make sure that the files to be included in the
>      patch are selected.
> 4. Add a commit comment.
> 5. Click Create patch.
>
> You can also create
>   patch on the base of your local history. To do that, open the local
>   history view for the desired directory, file or code fragment, as
>   described in the section Using Local History, right-click the desired
>   revision, and choose the Create Patch command on the context menu, or
>   click the create patch button img on the toolbar.

Comment: Hmm, strange. The context menu item is disabled in the history view of git window, but in the main version control window the option is available. Whatever :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my IntelliJ version (2020.2) under menu entry "VCS" I have only option "Create Patch from Local Changes..."

But I need from git commit, not from local, so found below option:

Right click on the git commit --> select "Create Patch..."

[image]